# using JQM, why is child div not overriding width and height from parents

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I have a JQM page that contains a Google Map.  The JQM page contains a header and a content section.  The content section itself holds the Google Map.

```
<div data-url="map-page" data-role="page" id="map-page" data-title="Test">

   <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h1>my header</h1>
   </div><!-- /header -->
   <div role="main" id="map-canvas" class="ui-content">          
      <p>some text that doesn't show up after map loads</p>
   </div><!-- /content -->
   <div data-role="panel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" data-theme="b" id="nav-panel">
      <h3>some random text here on this panel</h3>
   </div><!-- /panel -->
</div>
```

The page is styled very simply:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
}

#map-page, #map-canvas {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0px; 
 }
```

When I add a JQM panel to the page, the map does not display.  See http://jsfiddle.net/fRXPc/3/

I noticed that what JQM does behind the scenes is add a div with a class of `.ui-panel-wrapper`.  This div wraps the content div.  In other words, it's a child of the page and contains the content div.  Adding the `.ui-panel-wrapper` to my css page solves my problem.  See http://jsfiddle.net/fRXPc/2/

```
#map-page, #map-canvas, .ui-panel-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px; 
}
```

My question is: **why?**  I struggle with CSS - why doesn't setting the height directly for `map-canvas` do the trick?  I would think that it would override whatever values it gets from the panel wrapper div.  Is this basic CSS that I should know, or is some JQM sleight of hand happening?

Comment: It's basic CSS, to be able to calculate a percentual height the parent element must also have a height-style

Comment: Okay...clearly I need to read up on css.  I assumed that divs would inherit height styles from parents.  @dr.molle are you saying I need to set height explicitly for every element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

related to the comment:

As I said, when you set a percentual height-style the parent element must have a height-style too.

height-styles will not be inherited, you may read details in the reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property .

Basically you don't need to set the height for each element(there are default-values for each type of element), but when you want to force a specific **percentual** height, the parent element must have a height-style too. When the parent element also has a percentual height,  it's parent must have a height set too...and so on. 
In this specific case it means that all ancestors of `#map_canvas` must have a height-style(which is the case when you add the selector `.ui-panel-wrapper`, the height of the other ancestors will be set by you custom CSS or JQM)

The ancestors of `#map_canvas` are `html>body>div#map-page>div.ui-panel-wrapper`